# SVG Map w/ JS- Changing the states of multiple paths on hover

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, addeventlistener

I'm working on a clickable SVG map using the Raphael library and referencing details from [this tutorial](https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2013/07/18/create-clickable-svg-france-regions-map.html). I've also set up a working jsfiddle [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/nickpish/sbwyhhk4/). Basically, for each state in the map, I have paths defined for the map shape itself and for a state abbreviation label—in the case of the fiddle, I'm showing one state, PA, for demonstration purposes. I have separate arrays defined for "regions" and "labels". Currently, I have the hover state working for the state shape (changing its color to a dark blue), but would *also* like the state abbreviation label to change to white while hovering on the state.

I have the following arrays and loop defined to handle the hover and click events for the regions (shapes), and I would like to add logic that finds the matching label and changes its fill attribute to white on hover (and reverts on mouseout):

```
// REGION ARRAY
var regions = {};
regions["pennsylvania"] = {href: "#", path: map.path("path here")};

// LABEL ARRAY
var labels = {};
labels["pennsylvania"] = {href: "#", path: map.path("path here")};

// REGION STYLES
var animationSpeed = 500;
var shapeStyle = {
    fill: "#cdd6e9",
    stroke: "#fff",
    "stroke-width": 0.25,
    "stroke-linejoin": "round",
    cursor: "pointer"
};
var hoverStyle = {
  fill: "#0a3a62"
}

// REGION LOOP
for (var regionName in regions) {
    (function(region) {

        region.path.attr(shapeStyle);
        region.path[0].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
            region.path.animate(shapeStyle, animationSpeed);
        }, true);

        region.path[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            region.path.animate(hoverStyle, animationSpeed);
        }, true);

        region.path[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
            location.href = region.href;
        }, true);

    })(regions[regionName]);
}
```

Thus, in looping through the regions array, how would I adjust the script to find the matching label in the labels array and change its fill state? Thanks for any insight here.

Comment: Why not pass regionName (rather than regions[regionName]) as the function parameter. Then  in the loop you can access both regions and labels via the name ? Or pass it both (regions[regionName],labels[regionName]) as the parameters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the label events while you're setting your region events so you can match on the `regionName`.  You can either use the `let` keyword on your `for` loop or you can pass the `regionName` or both (`regions[regionName]`,`labels[regionName]`)  to the immediate function as @Ian suggested.

```
var labelHoverStyle = { // add
    fill: '#FFFFFF'
}

var labelStyle = {
    fill: "#0a3a62",
    stroke: "#0a3a62",
    "stroke-width": 0.25,
    "stroke-linejoin": "round",
    cursor: "pointer" 
}
```

**Using `Let`**

```
for(let regionName in regions) { // notice the variable declaration
    (function (region) {

        if (regionName == "district-of-columbia") {
            region.path.attr(shapeStyle2);
            region.path[0].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
            region.path.animate(shapeStyle2, animationSpeed);
            labels[regionName].path.animate(labelStyle, animationSpeed);
            }, true);
        } else {
            region.path.attr(shapeStyle);
            region.path[0].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
            region.path.animate(shapeStyle, animationSpeed);
            labels[regionName].path.animate(labelStyle, animationSpeed);
            }, true);
        }

        region.path[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            region.path.animate(hoverStyle, animationSpeed);
            labels[regionName].path.animate(labelHoverStyle, animationSpeed);
        }, true);

        region.path[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
            location.href = region.href;         
        }, true);

    })(regions[regionName]);
}
```

**Passing `regionName` or (`regions[regionName],labels[regionName]`)**

```
for(var regionName in regions) {
    (function (region, label) { // notice the parameters

        if (region.href.indexOf('district-of-columbia') > -1) {
            region.path.attr(shapeStyle2);
            region.path[0].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
            region.path.animate(shapeStyle2, animationSpeed);
            label.path.animate(labelStyle, animationSpeed);
            }, true);
        } else { 
            region.path.attr(shapeStyle);
            region.path[0].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
            region.path.animate(shapeStyle, animationSpeed);
            label.path.animate(labelStyle, animationSpeed);
            }, true);
        } 

        region.path[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            region.path.animate(hoverStyle, animationSpeed);
            label.path.animate(labelHoverStyle, animationSpeed);
        }, true);

      ....

    })(regions[regionName], labels[regionName]); // notice the arguments
}
```

Comment: Not sure regionName would be available there without a closure, I may be wrong though.

Comment: @Ian I may also be completely wrong but how I understand it is that the variable declared at the loop is scoped to the outer function which gives lexical-scope access to the inner immediate function.  Seems to work in the jsfiddle... for "pennsylvania" at least.

Comment: @ian thanks much for the replies- I've updated the fiddle and will try adding to the full map and see if all is working

Comment: @ian - it appears we might need to make a further adjustment after all, as after adding all the regions, it seems like only one label highlights. I've update the fiddle here- https://jsfiddle.net/nickpish/sbwyhhk4/ with the entire map; do I need to include a closure? Note that I have an if/else statement for DC as I'm applying a custom style for that region. Thanks again for your assistance!

Comment: @StevenB. It appears I may need to add a closure after all- I just updated my fiddle with all the regions, and only one label highlights as configured- would you mind taking a look?

Comment: @nickpish see the updated answer that follows @Ians suggestions.  You will also probably need to move the `labels` definition above this `for` loop.

Comment: @StevenB. Thanks very much! I just updated the fiddle and all seems to be working. For future reference, could you briefly describe how exactly your edits fix the issue? My understanding of closures is somewhat limited.

Comment: @nickpish MDN has a good article that goes over closures and function factories [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and they go over your exact use case [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake).  My mistake was not using the `let` keyword (see above).  The issue was that the closures all shared the same lexical environment so it was only using the last iteration's `regionName`.

Comment: @StevenB. Awesome- thanks for the explanation; I will check out the resources you mentioned.